# Why do I have 3 extra contacts on my phone when using Google contacts?

Tags: iphone, contacts, gmail

I have my iPhone 11 setup to use Google Contacts.  I've been using my contact list both on my gmail account / computer and my iPhone 11.

Why are there 3 extra contacts on my phone but not my computer.

I have 209 on my gmail contacts but 212 on my phone?

The phone appears to have 3 extra but I don't know were they came from?

Comment: Perhaps they came with your phone or provider  e.g. a number to call for voicemail or for your balance (if you're pay and go) etc.

Answer (score 1):

These additional contacts may be included in the SIM card you got from your provider. To easily find them, turn off Google Contacts in Settings->Password&Accounts->"your Google account" and select "delete synced contacts from iPhone" (don't worry, they still we be stored on Google itself). Then open the Contacts app, you now should see only these three contacts.

Comment: I found that one of the extras is myself.  iPhone automatically creates this and adds it to the list.  Another one was a virtual card I got from a professor.